# Python regular expressions to print 2 items from a match

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to extract the process id and the word 'ERROR' from the following line.

```
July bad_process[12345]: ERROR
```

With the following code I can print the process id but cannot print the word 'ERROR'. If I return the 0 index I get this line.

```
[12345]: ERROR
```

If I return the 1 index I get  just the process id

```
123456
```

But returning index 2 I do not get the word 'ERROR'. How do I return the id and also the word 'ERROR'?

```
def extract_pid(log_line):
    regex = r"\[(\d+)\]: [A-Z]+"
    result = re.search(regex, log_line)
    if result is None:
        return ""
    return result[1]

print(extract_pid(log))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a second capturing group and use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to find all matches.

From [re.search - documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search):

> **re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)**
>
> Scan through string looking for the **first location** where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding MatchObject instance.

```
import re

def extract_pid(log_line):
    regex = r"\[(\d+)\]: ([A-Z]+)"           # added grouping for 2nd group
    matches = re.findall(regex, log_line)
    return matches

print( extract_pid("""July bad_process[12345]: ERROR
July bad_process[42]: INFO""") )
```

Output:

```
[('12345', 'ERROR'), ('42', 'INFO')]
```